# Java Regular Expressio NEFT\\(SBINH[0-9]{11}\\)

Tags: java, regex

For Java Regular Expression `NEFT\\(SBINH[0-9]{11}\\)`

I expect `NEFT(SBINH01234567895)` to be a valid match.

But turns out that it isn't a match. Can you please guide me where my understanding is going wrong.

Comment: It is!! https://regex101.com/r/eI8lQ6/1

Comment: Now I’m confused… is it `\\(` or `\(`? Before the edit there were both versions… and edits shouldn’t fix the code.

Comment: @Xufox - it is `\\(` (and it should be) :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah, but edits shouldn’t fix the code…

Comment: No Space before NEFT

Comment: @Xufox - Since teh regex was not inside a code block, it was showing only one `\`

Comment: @Xufox: `\\(` is the sequence `\(` when specified in string literal. People usually paste the code from Java, which is why you see `\\(`

Comment: NEFT\(SBINH[0-9]{11}\) Matches NEFT(SBINH01234567895)                                                                         But what will match if there are 2 \ like   NEFT\\(SBINH[0-9]{11}\\)

Comment: @VinodJayachandran: `"NEFT(SBINH01234567895)".matches("NEFT\\(SBINH[0-9]{11}\\)")`

Comment: @TheLostMind Oh, I didn’t know that StackOverflow formatted backslashes in this way… well, sorry then. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :  NEFT[\(]SBINH[0-9]\{11\}[\)]